# Sort DIV's after clicking a button which moves you to another site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have 2 pages:

1. mysite.com/site1
2. mysite.com/site2

On `site 1` I have a few buttons (all of them redirecting to site2)
On `site 2` I have a few boxes with content (divs)

Is there a simple way to only show the divs I want to on site2 based on which button was clicked on `site1`? I remember something with the redirect?

For example, when I click button one, I end up on `site2` with only box 2 and 3 visible, but if I'd've clicked button 2, I only see box 1 on `site2`.

Answer (score 0):

This could possibly be a huge answer, but I will try to simplify it.

Basically, you want to use `ajax`- **[`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** here and with that you can just get content of other page.

Say you have below markup in `site1`

```
<button id="button1" class="btn" data-load="#div1">Load Div1 from Site 2</button>
<button id="button2" class="btn" data-load="#div2">Load Div1 from Site 2</button>
<div id="loadContent"></div>
```

Now what you can do is `onclick` of any `button` above fetch its `data-load` value and make a valid `url` and pass it through `$.load`. For Example.

```
$('.btn').on('click',function(){
   var url="/site2"+$(this).data('load');
   //url here will be www.mysite.com/site2#div1 or www.mysite.com/site2#div2 based on button clicked
   $('#loadContent').load(url,function(){
      //#div1 from site2 will be loaded within loadContent element
      //callback function after content is loaded
   })
   //or just $("#loadContent").load(url);
});
```

Comment: the problem is it is a WP site, so complicated to get to certain elements

Answer (score 0):

You can have each button send a different query string to site 2 representing the allowed divs (e.g. mysite.com/site2?div1=true&div2=false)

Of course you will have to handle the query string on site2's javascript...

Answer (score 0):

You can set id's for the elements in your 2nd page and then do the following:

First redirect to your page with the following Button:

```
<button onclick='window.location="page2.html#yourid"' >klick me</button>
```

Use the following Script in your  page2.html:

```
var url=document.URL;

if(url.substr(url.indexOf("#"))=="#id1")
{
    //delete Elements

}
else
{
    if(url.substr(url.indexOf("#"))=="#id2")
    {
        //delete Elements 
    }
    else
    {
        if(url.substr(url.indexOf("#"))=="#id3")
        {
            //delete Elements 
        }
    }
}
```

replace the id's with the ids, you have chosen and delete the Elements in the if statements, which you want to delete:

```
document.getElementById("id#").remove();
```

Comment: Problem is it is a wordpress site and the code with the page with buttons looks like this:

Comment: In this case I dont know how to help you. I Never worked with WP before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is it is a wp page and the button page looks like this (site 1):

```
 <div class="col-sm-12" onclick="window.location.href='<?=get_permalink($child->ID)?>'">
                                    <div class="r-targets-block-content">
                                        <div class="r-targets-block-bg" style="background:url('<?=$thumbnail?>') center top no-repeat"></div>
                                        <div class="r-targets-descr-block">
                                            <div class="r-targets-title"><?=$child->post_title?></div>
                                            <div class="r-targets-subtitle"></div>
                                            <div class="r-targets-button-block">
                                                <?=r_arrowed_button(
                                                    get_permalink($child->ID),
                                                    "SEE MORE", 
                                                    ["standard", "small", "border-yellow", "arrow-right"]
                                                )?>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="r-targets-recomendation-block-null"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```